# MySQL and ASP.NET (vb) issue with TIME automatically being added to DATE field

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I'm having a problem with a MySQL query for returning the "last visit" field in a table.

Originally I had:

```
select fname, lname, last_visit from patient where isactive = 1 and uid = 1
```

Which worked perfectly in MySQL, but as soon as the query is executed by my ASP.NET app, it adds in the time field also to the date area. So `2011-12-12` becomes `12/12/2011 12:00:00 AM`

I tried this also, with no improvement:

```
select fname, lname, DATE(last_visit) as last_visit from patient where isactive = 1 and uid = 1 order by lname
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you storing this date in a DateTime object?

Comment: I mean in VB.net, what data type is it being stored into?

Answer (score 2):

A .NET DateTime object always has a Time component. In your app, you can just ignore it though.

```vb
Dim myDate As New DateTime(2011,12,12)

Dim dateAndTime As String = myDate.ToString() 'Prints 12/12/2011 12:00:00 AM

Dim onlyDate As String = myDate.ToShortDateString() 'Prints 12/12/2011
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql will add the time by default if its a datetime field. Try implementing a custom date and time format string. [MSDN article about custom date/time formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#Y342)